# Utilizing Bootstrap's typeahead as a search function

Tags: search, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead, typeahead

I've got typeahead working just fine, but I am too inexperienced with the Javascript to understand how to turn the typed results into a link.

```
<input type="text"
                       class="span3"
                       data-provide="typeahead"
                       placeholder="City Search:"
                       data-items="6"
                       autocomplete="off" 
                       data-source=[&quot;Neuchatel&quot;,&quot;Moutier&quot;]">
```

So, I really just want to know how to turn the strings from data-source into links to other pages. Hopefully this is fairly simple.

thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can turn the strings into links easily..

```
<input type="text" data-provide="typeahead" data-source="[&quot;/foo.html&quot;,&quot;http://www.google.com&quot;,&quot;/about.html&quot;]">
```

Are you also looking to take the link from the input and then navigate to the selected page?

*EDIT:* **Navigate to item selected in typeahead**..

In this case you'd define an object map that contain keys (label) and values (url) like..

```
var data = {
  "login":"/login",
  "home":"/",
  "user":"/user",
  "tags":"/tags",
  "google":"http://google.com"
};
```

Then you'd initiate the typeahead. The `source` and `updater` functions would be defined to handle 1) creating the typeahead data source array from the map object, and 2) navigate to the appropriate url when an item is selected..

```
$('.typeahead').typeahead({
  minLength:2,
  updater: function (item) {
        /* navigate to the selected item */
        window.location.href = data[item];
    },
  source: function (typeahead, query) {
    var links=[];
    for (var name in data){
        links.push(name); 
    }

    return links;
    }
});
```

### [Demo on Bootply](http://bootply.com/61445)

Comment: thx, I am indeed trying to then navigate to the page. The idea is for the user to type in a city, the name pops up and they select it. Then they are directed to that page. kind of like a simple html link, but included within the string.

Comment: This guy seems to be on the same track, but I don't understand how to store the exact URLs. http://www.webmaster-source.com/2012/11/07/getting-more-from-twitter-bootstraps-typeahead-library/

Comment: @Skelly why not use a custom template for this?