# Implement typeahead such that items are links

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead

How can I implement bootstrap-typeahead.js in such a way that it looks at a long list of links and the suggested options are clickable to take you to their specific page?

For example, on twitter's site, if you search something in their searchbox, some matches for specific people return as links that allow you to click them to go directly to the page rather than having to search them. By default, typeahead just replaces the current input with the result you click rather than taking you to a page that corresponds to that link.

The list is just a bunch of hyperlinks.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I ended up using twitter's [typeahead.js](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js).

Answer (score 1):

You can make the typeahead `source` a list of links, and then use the `updater` function to navigate to the selected link. See my answer to: [Utilizing Bootstrap's typeahead as a search function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16568152/utilizing-bootstraps-typeahead-as-a-search-function)

If you only want to show the actual urls (links) in the typeahead do something like this..

```
var links = [
  "/login",
  "/",
  "/user",
  "/tags"
];

$('.typeahead').typeahead({
  minLength:2,
  updater: function (item) {
    /* navigate to the selected item */
    window.location.href = item;
  },
  source: links
});
```

### [**Demo**](http://bootply.com/61700)

Comment: Would you happen to know how I can implement this in rails? Could I use gon and assign `gon.items = Items.all` and then use that as a var? The problem I have there is I don't know how to add the URL side of the value to the key, as I do not know if there is a Items.url function in rails. My application already uses bootstrap, how can I modify the typeahead such that it works this way?

Comment: Sorry, i don't know how in rails

Comment: So does this answer your question? You didn't mention rails in your question.

Comment: Yeah, the functionary you have provided here is exactly what I am looking for, but I'd need to implement it in rails somehow, I probably should've mentioned that. I made another question pertaining to how to implement this type of search in rails specifically. Thank you.